# Why doesn't this model plane fly?

Tags: aerodynamics

I have been designing a model plane for Design Technology for the past month or so, and today I laser cut my final design and assembled, it then tested it. Upon testing the plane does not get any lift, whereas the previous testing model which was virtually the same did.
The plane is built using Balsa Wood, and Assembled with hot glue (I used as little glue as possible to reduce weight :) )

Any Ideas?

Image:

[image]

Comment: Where is the centre of gravity? The wings look awfully far forward, and if the centre of gravity is behind the wings the plane will tend to dive into the ground.

Comment: @John: Right. In a back-slide. Planes normally have the center of gravity forward of the center of lift. Then the tail pushes *down* to keep the nose from dropping. It's called [*decalage*](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/aoastab.html#sec-basic-stability).

Comment: First try it as a glider. The shape of the wing doesn't matter that much. What matters is the balance. The main wing has to be far enough back so it is nose-heavy, and of course it needs a tail. Then if you throw it fast enough, it will glide. Then if you give it a propeller it will go farther.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the wings does not appear right to produce lift. More convex on top, less on the bottom, would be better

And planes often have dihedral, wingtips raised, for stability.

EDIT - This answer was too hasty. The comments below are much better.

Comment: yeah that was my first thought, so if I add a larger curve on the top, and a flatter bottom for the wing it would help it?

Comment: This is wrong. If the wing is inclined with respect to the incoming wind, it'll produce a force. Even a flat plate is capable of doing this. Are you sure your plane is stable? Check that the neutral point and CoG are correctly situated.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: yes, my guess is that the CoG is in the wrong place.

Comment: @Pranav: yes, and the correct situation is - the CoG needs to be *forward* of the CoL. Moving the wing back, or putting a small weight on the nose, should enable it to glide stably. The reason is - the tail lifts *down*, so lower speed drops the nose, which increases speed. Higher speed raises the nose, which reduces speed. If the CoG and CoL are at the same place, it will have no stability in speed, and will fly a choppy up and down motion. If the CoG is *behind* the CoL, it could very well back-slide.

Comment: @Pranav: [*This video*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MB9JDBe4wA) shows what happens when the loading shifts aft.

Comment: @Mike, I know what happens. I wrote correctly situated because if you find it out yourself, you remember it forever.

Comment: @Pranav: Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Most model planes don't have wings aerodynamic enough to lift it by those means. Honestly, put a rotor strong enough on one side of a plain board and it will fly also.

Comment: How, then, do you propose model airplanes fly?

Comment: Little inclination, light weight and brute force for propulsion. Then the contact pressure on the downside will suffice. Really guys, go in a shop and have a look ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to tell why a plane does not fly just looking at a couple of pictures of it!

My advice is to go to a soft ground (like >10cm tall grass) and try to launch it by hand like a paper plane and see how it behaves. If it does not get a decent glide there there are very few hopes for it to lift by itself.

In this way you will point out stability problems and you can get a starting point to correct the geometry, placement of the wings, tail elevators, COG position and so on.